# Pandas resampler interpolate is not interpolating correctly

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm working with a pandas series and I want to resample this data to get 10 second intervals. The series I'm working with:

```
volSeries.head(20)

Time
2018-10-14 12:00:00    6.0
2018-10-14 12:00:02    5.0
2018-10-14 12:02:32    6.0
2018-10-14 12:02:57    5.0
2018-10-14 12:03:22    6.0
2018-10-14 12:03:27    5.0
2018-10-14 12:17:42    6.0
2018-10-14 12:17:47    5.0
2018-10-14 12:17:57    5.0
2018-10-14 12:18:07    6.0
2018-10-14 12:18:12    5.0
2018-10-14 12:18:17    6.0
2018-10-14 12:18:32    5.0
2018-10-14 12:18:47    6.0
2018-10-14 12:18:57    5.0
2018-10-14 12:19:27    6.0
2018-10-14 12:19:37    5.0
2018-10-14 12:20:37    6.0
2018-10-14 12:20:57    5.0
2018-10-14 12:21:07    6.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

When I try to resample, the output is linearly increasing which doesn't match the data:

```
volumeResampler = volSeries.resample('10S')
resampledVolumeData = volumeResampler.interpolate('linear')
resampledVolumeData.head(20)

Time
2018-10-14 12:00:00    6.000000
2018-10-14 12:00:10    6.198148
2018-10-14 12:00:20    6.396296
2018-10-14 12:00:30    6.594444
2018-10-14 12:00:40    6.792593
2018-10-14 12:00:50    6.990741
2018-10-14 12:01:00    7.188889
2018-10-14 12:01:10    7.387037
2018-10-14 12:01:20    7.585185
2018-10-14 12:01:30    7.783333
2018-10-14 12:01:40    7.981481
2018-10-14 12:01:50    8.179630
2018-10-14 12:02:00    8.377778
2018-10-14 12:02:10    8.575926
2018-10-14 12:02:20    8.774074
2018-10-14 12:02:30    8.972222
2018-10-14 12:02:40    9.170370
2018-10-14 12:02:50    9.368519
2018-10-14 12:03:00    9.566667
2018-10-14 12:03:10    9.764815
Freq: 10S, Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

You can see when comparing graphs before and after resampling that it is clearly not interpolating correctly.

Before Resampling:

[image: Volume before Resampling]

After Resampling:

[image: Volume after Resampling]

Comment: Seems to work fine giving all `6`'s on my computer.

Comment: What is your expected output? I mean can you share sample data of your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be with the frequency at which I interpolate. The values I'm interpolating are not consistently spaced with the minimum spacing of 2 seconds and the maximum of 37080 between adjacent points.

If I resample at anything <= 4 seconds the interpolation works just fine. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: There is an option to `interpolate(method= 'index')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the interpolation with values outside the frequency window, you can insert the frequency you want in your initial dataframe, sort it, then do the interpolation and after select only the values at the exact frequency you want:

```py
# example from your sample, change the end date
sample = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'time': pd.date_range(
            '2018-10-14 12:00:00', '2018-10-14 12:22:00', freq='10S'
        )
    }
)
df = (
    pd.concat(
        [
            volSeries.to_frame(),
            sample,
        ],
        sort=False,
    )
    .sort_values(['time'])
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['time'])
    .set_index('time')
    .interpolate('index')
    .loc[sample['time'].values, :]
)
```

This gives:

```
                       volume
time                         
2018-10-14 12:00:00  6.000000
2018-10-14 12:00:10  5.053333
2018-10-14 12:00:20  5.120000
2018-10-14 12:00:30  5.186667
2018-10-14 12:00:40  5.253333
2018-10-14 12:00:50  5.320000
2018-10-14 12:01:00  5.386667
2018-10-14 12:01:10  5.453333
2018-10-14 12:01:20  5.520000
2018-10-14 12:01:30  5.586667
2018-10-14 12:01:40  5.653333
2018-10-14 12:01:50  5.720000
2018-10-14 12:02:00  5.786667
2018-10-14 12:02:10  5.853333
2018-10-14 12:02:20  5.920000
2018-10-14 12:02:30  5.986667
2018-10-14 12:02:40  5.680000
2018-10-14 12:02:50  5.280000
2018-10-14 12:03:00  5.120000
2018-10-14 12:03:10  5.520000
```